# How do I fetch the last element of an array in Swift?

Tags: swift

I can do this:

```
var a = [1,5,7,9,22]
a.count               // 5
a[a.count - 1]        // 22
a[a.endIndex - 1]     // 22
```

but surely there's a prettier way?

Comment: What's wrong with that way? Presumably, you can provide your own extension to add a ".lastElement" method.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with it except that it's ugly.

Comment: Maybe not wrong but prone to one-off errors. I'd write an extension as mentioned in the answers.

Comment: I was hoping Swift has `lastIndex` var, which available in Kotlin. Seems like I'd have to stick with `endIndex - 1` for now.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Update: Swift 2.0 now includes `first:T?` and `last:T?` properties built-in.

---

When you need to you can make the built-in Swift API's prettier by providing your own extensions, e.g:

```
extension Array {
    var last: T {
        return self[self.endIndex - 1]
    }
}
```

This lets you now access the last element on any array with:

```
[1,5,7,9,22].last
```

Comment: Thanks! BTW, `endIndex` doesn't need to be referenced via `self`.

Comment: As of Xcode6-Beta5, the `last` property is built-in (as is `first`). It returns `nil` if the array is empty.

Comment: The problem with this implementation is that it does crash if the Array is empty.

Comment: If we're going to change the last element, we should check if array is empty or not at first.

Comment: If you ain't first you're last - Ricky Bobby

Comment: you do not need this anymore in Swift 3. See below for better answers. .last is builtin.

Answer (score 109):

As of `beta5` there is now a `first` and `last` property

> In addition to Array acquiring first and last, the lazy collections also implement first (and last if they can index bidirectionally), as well as isEmpty.

Comment: would be nice to include a link to this documentation

Comment: don't tell me, tell @joseph.hainline :)

Comment: Would be nice with an example

Comment: Thanks for this! Interestingly, the iOS 10 master/detail template in Xcode 8.3.3 still uses code of the form x[x.count-1] -- but MUCH longer -- rather than x.last.

Answer (score 26):

You can fetch the last element of an Array by using the `last` property.

Code:

```
let lastElement = yourArray.last
```

Answer (score 12):

swift 5:

```
if let last = a.last {
   print(last)
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can also get and remove last element from array
`removeLast()`

Example:

```
var array = [1, 2, 3]
let removed = array.removeLast()
// array is [1, 2]
// removed is 3
```

Taken from Apple docs (this source expired but you can find examples in this [documentation page](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID107))

Comment: Unlike the ObjC removeLast feature, Swift 4 isn’t smart enough to know if there are no elements left in the array and will crash if tried on an empty array.

Answer (score 2):

edit for swift 2.2

```
extension Array {
    var last: Element {
        return self[self.endIndex - 1]
    }
}
```